# ANT: 'filterchain doesn't support the nested "suffixlines" element.'

Tags: ant

I'm fairly new to ANT and I'm attempting to write an ANT target to copy all the lines from 'Temp1.txt', that contain the prefix "Foo ", to 'Temp2.txt', then suffix them with " Bar".

Example:

*Temp1.txt*:

Foo 5mt4GANE
YVDZujA0
Foo Eqi5zIZe

-->

*Temp2.txt*:

Foo 5mt4GANE Bar
Foo Eqi5zIZe Bar

Here are the contents of my target so far:

```
<copy
    file = "Temp1.txt"
    tofile = "Temp2.txt">
    <filterchain>
        <linecontains>
            <contains value = "Foo " />
        </linecontains>
        <trim/>
        <ignoreblank/>
        <suffixlines 
            suffix = " Bar" />                      
    </filterchain>
</copy>
```

This target works perfectly with 'prefixlines', but with 'suffixlines' I get the error: *'filterchain doesn't support the nested "suffixlines" element.'*. According to the ANT manual, I seem to be doing nothing wrong. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Which Ant version are you using?  suffixlines was added at v1.8.0 according to the docs: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#suffixlines

Comment: If that is the problem, you could use a [scriptfilter](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#scriptfilter) instead.